# Django, a tag, href. How to go to upper level?

Tags: python, html, django

Good day to all.
Trying to understand django, stucked with href problem.
I have 2 pages - 127.0.0.1:8000/index/ and 127.0.0.1:8000/events/
On index, there is a  tag. I whant it to point to /events/, but when i set href to '/events/' od '../events' or '.events' - django send me to 'index/events'.
What i am doing wrong?
Thaix for you answers

Comment: Have you tried using ".."?

Comment: Yes. No effect at all

Comment: Show us some code of what you tried so far, maybe we can help better.

Answer (score 0):

To link to another template you have to use the `{% url %}` tag. This will look for the view that you are trying to link to in your urls.py file.
So, your link should look like this:

```
<a href="{% url appname:viewname %}">
```

The viewname above refers to the name you have set for your view in the name parameter of your path function in your urls.py file.